# Why does PySide still require QString for textChanged SIGNAL?

Tags: python, pyside, signals-slots, qstring

My previous understanding was that PySide does not require QString. Yet I found that PySide (I am using v1.2.1 with Python v2.7.5) appears to be inconsistent about this depending on how I wire up my Signals and Slots:

```
# This Way of wiring up signals and slots requires str
le = QLineEdit()
slotOnChanged = self.onChanged
le.textChanged[str].connect(slotOnChanged)

# But this Way requires QString
le = QLineEdit()
signalTextChanged = SIGNAL("textChanged(QString)")
slotOnChanged = self.onChanged
le.connect(signalTextChanged, slotOnChanged)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that PySide does not require the QString class, but are mistaken that there is any inconsistency.

PySide/PyQt are generally quite thin wrappers around Qt's C++ library. However, the signal and slot syntax is one of the few areas where there is a significant deviation from this. The syntax used by Qt (the second method in your examples), requires detailed knowledge of C++ signature arguments, and is easy to get wrong. Also, from a python perspective, the syntax is needlessly verbose, and rather "unpythonic". Because of this, PySide/PyQt have added some syntactic "sugar" which provides an alternative, more pythonic, syntax for signals and slots. This is used by the first method in your examples.

The specific reason why QString has to be used in the second method, is that Qt signals are defined *statically* as part of a C++ class. So the argument to SIGNAL has to quite precisely match the C++ definition in order for the connection to be successful. But note that the argument to SIGNAL doesn't require the QString *class* to be available - it just requires the use of the string "QString" in the signature.

The "old", C++ way of connecting signals will probably remain available for quite some time (for backward compatibillity if nothing else). But it's generally better to use the "new", pythonic way whenever possible. It's just much clearer, and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In short: efficiency.

A QString is made up of QChar(s).  These provide cross platform compatibility between the C++ and Python bindings (as well as for easier language translation); a string in Python versus a string in C++ are usually different.  Qt provides their own.

textChanged(QString) uses QString because ...
1) it can provide a more agnostic type between the language bindings,
2) it avoids the type conversion that happens in the first example and is more efficient.

[Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#details) is the detailed description of QString.  Note the link on implicit sharing.

[Here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide) are examples of other possibilities that are more idiomatic for PySide.